# Conditional InputTemplate body AWS eventbridge rule using SAM template

Tags: amazon-web-services, slack-api, aws-sam, aws-event-bridge

I created an aws event bridge rule for slack. Now i would like to display different template based on a condition. The condition variable and its value will be part of the event message. I declare a variable into InputPathMap and used this variable as a condition parameter. I am getting an error when I deployed using SAM. It shows the variable value is null and did not deploy code to aws.

partial info of my rule.

```
...
InputTransformer:
            InputPathsMap:             
              "actionMsg" : "$.detail.actionMsg"
              "actionValue" : "$.detail.actionValue"
            InputTemplate: !Sub >
              !If [
                     <actionValue>, 
                        {
                        "channel": "slackChannelName",
                        "text": "condition 1 : <actionMsg>"
                        ...(more)
                        }, 
                        {
                         "channel": "slackChannelName",
                         "text": "condition 2 : <actionMsg>"
                         ...(more)
                        }
                    ]
```

I searched in google and saw the aws condition info.
Can I set condition with the variable which I defined? Would you please give me an example, hints or link? I would appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

This won't be possible to do within a single EventBridge Rule. You'll have to define separate 2 rules with an Event Pattern for each unique `$detail.actionValue` that you care about.

A possible solution might be to define a rule with its own input transform and event pattern for matching your first condition

```json
{ 
  "...": "...",
  "detail": {
    "...": "...",
    "actionValue": ["foo"]
}
```

Then define a "default rule" with your default input transform that catches everything except `actionValue == "foo"`

```json
{ 
  "...": "...",
  "detail": {
    "...": "...",
    "actionValue": [ {"anything-but": ["foo"]} ]
}
```